# Open a project with .cs extension files?

Tags: c#, .net, macos, visual-studio, oop

i have a folder with a lot files; in the main folder have a .sln file extensión and other folder with lot files .cs and .config, i think that is about of a .NET project, how do open this project? is trought Visual Studio? i have Visual Studio 2022 for mac.

My Visual Studio 2022 for mac dont allow me select the main folder for open it like a Solution, how do open it correctly?

Comment: On PC the Visual Studio interface has a File menu, with an Open sub-menu, in which "Project/Solution" is an available option.  Is that not the case on Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the main menu in Visual Studio...Select `Open a project or solution`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Make sure if you want to open it as a folder or as a solution and check if your .net project matches that version of Visual Studio (maybe you need an older version, but you have not specified the .net project's version number or the framework's version number if it has one), although they look very similar, you can see more files and folders inside if you open it as a folder. If you open the project as a solution you will be able to see the project architecture better. Opening it as a solution is better if you have a .net project.

Answer (score 1):

Try opening the .sln file in visual studio